# HTML/JAVASCRIPT Animation like on storj.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this site [Storj.io](https://storj.io/). I really like the design of the site and was looking at the header. There is a background-image and then on top of this there are those points that are moving. How can such a animation be achieved? Is this done with html5 and how or is JavaScript used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspection reveals they are using Particles.js

[Particles JS](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

They provide documentation to get you started and achieve the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks the seems to be the right thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad for a complete answer. Try asking about smaller parts of it when you get stuck.

**From Scratch:** In essence you'll want to look into using the `<canvas>` element to draw particles. Take a look at [this simple example](http://hop.ie/particles/fountain.html) of what can be done. [Here is a blog post](https://learnsome.co/blog/particles/) on particles with canvas to get you going (which culminates with the previous example).

**With a library:** https://storj.io is using [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/). But that doesn't tell you how it's accomplished. On the plus side though, the library can easily be included from https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/ (see the demo [on codepen](https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso)).